# Error occur when clicking login button for IE only

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11

```
  driver.FindElement(By.Id("inputUsername")).SendKeys("test");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("inputPassword")).SendKeys("test2018");
        driver.FindElement(By.TagName("button")).Submit();
```

try to use the above and execute it in internet explorer. Upon clicking the login button error message "A exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server" occured. But this only happen in IE. Other browser doing fine when executing the code above. Anyone know what is the problem with it?

Comment: Never use IE driver to automate. Webdrivers are best when you use Firefox and Chrome. There are some other tools like watir-classic available when you want to automate IE, WebDriber is not a right choice. Even if you fix this problem another one will soon wells up.

Comment: @Rajagopalan watir-classic is another automation testing tools like selenium?

Comment: It would not use WebDriber to drive the browser, it uses WIN32OLE implementation to drive the browser. You can open any window application using WIN32OLE and you can start operating at that application using the given methods. Watir-classic uses that to drive the IE and it's not available for other browsers.

Comment: @Rajagopalan  so if i wanna perform a test for a website which require to test by using IE how? can u guide since you say webdriver is not a good tool for IE

Comment: Hi sure, here is the material you can learn. Remember this gem is deprecated now in the favor of WATIR which sits on the top of selenium now but still it performs outstandingly. https://github.com/watir/watir_meta/wiki/Cheat-Sheet if you have any questions please ask the question by including WATIR and WATIR-classic tag.

Comment: @Kevin Update the question with the relevant _HTML_ and your _exact code trial_

Comment: @Rajagopalan Your comments dismissing the IE driver out of hand are unwarranted, and show a lack of understanding about the driver’s architecture. Moreover, I don’t recall seeing any issue reports with appropriate reproduction steps or pull requests submitted from you to the Selenium project to help make the driver better.

Comment: @JimEvans Microsoft is no longer giving any support to IE, it moved to Edge now. I can't raise a bug to selenium project, I have to raise the bug to IE driver if I were to do but that was deprecated.

Comment: @Rajagopalan Where do you think the IE driver comes from? It is now, and always has been, produced by the [Selenium project](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/master/cpp). Yes, there was an alternative mode produced by Microsoft, which was deprecated, but it was never used by many people.